# launch specific shells with initialization code at emacs startup

Tags: shell, emacs

when my daemonized emacs starts up, I'd like to automatically create several shell buffers, which each run some initialization code.

e.g. in one (with a buffer named `*foo*`) I would like to run

```
cd devel/foo
source setup.sh
```

in another (named `*sudo*`) I would like to run

```
exec sudo -i
```

and in (named `*journal*`) another I'd like to run

```
journalctl -f
```

I can put this in my init.el

```
(shell "*foo*")
(shell "*sudo*")
(shell "*journal*")
```

which launches and names all the buffers, but I don't know how to run the initial commands. Note that I still want them to be normal interactive shell mode buffers, as if I had started them up by hand and typed in the initialization code.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation of the `shell` function (cf. `C-h f shell RET`) says explicitly:

```
If a file `~/.emacs_SHELLNAME' exists, or `~/.emacs.d/init_SHELLNAME.sh',
it is given as initial input.
```

So, you could get what you want by creating a file named `~/.emacs.d/init_*foo*.sh` and containing:

```
cd devel/foo
source setup.sh
```

And so on for the other files.

Beware of the '*' in the name of the files!

If you want to do it with "standard" emacs-lisp code, you might want to have a look at the hook variable:

```
C-h v comint-input-sender RET
```

which standard contents is the function:

```
C-h f comint-simple-send RET
```